# For each value I want to apply a div

Tags: php, foreach

I'm working on a script and here's my problem.
I have an array who list name of persons.

For each person I want to apply them one street (1st street for the first person then the 2nd street for the 2nd person). Here's the code

```
<div class="adress">1 st St Louis</div> 
<div class="adress"> st St Josef</div> 

<?php 

$name = array("John", "Matt");

foreach ($name as $item) {
    echo '<p>'.$item.'</p>';
}

?>
```

I'm aware that I can put the adress in the array but this is not the way I want to do this.

So if there any solution let me know ;)

Comment: Associative arrays were invented for such a scope. Did you think about them? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need an array with the address like

```
$address = array("1 st blabla", "2nd street")
```

then use a [for iterator](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.for.php) instead of foreach, that way you can access to the same index of both arrays

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($address); $i = $i+1 )
{
    echo "<p> Person: ".$name[$i]." in street: ".$address[$i]."</p>";
}
```

That way you will print

Person: John in street 1 st blabla

Person: Matt in street 2nd street